# How to match new-line character using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the special characters and the breaks using a regex to cleanse the string so that I'm left with only the following string 'All release related activities' extracted from the following line:

```
{"Well":"\n\n\t\n\t\n\n\t\n\tAll release related activities\n\n\t"}
```

I've tried the regex `^{.Well":"` and I'm able to match till  the first colon appears. How do I match the \n characters in the string?

Comment: If that where valid JSON, you could use the JSONSlurper and trim

Comment: Pranay the sample that you provided, is that a single line string ? or literally multiline since it has many \n

Comment: Would `(?<!\\)[^\\]*?(?=})` work for you?

Comment: Then why is this tagged with groovy? Wouldn't it be better to tag with just regexp and maybe the actual tool you are using (assuming there are special cases too)?

Comment: cfrick, I'd checked the available tags for the tool, wasn't available, although the tool uses Groovy scripts so I mentioned it, although it's unimportant as regexps won't really change whatever language I use

Comment: Are you missing a final `"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure about the prefix of "well:" So I am basically providing you with a basic regex:

```
^\{[^}]*?(?:\\[ntr])+([^}]+)\}
```

and replace by:

```
\1
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/mIG8q4/2)

Comment: What do you mean by replace with \1?

Comment: You may look into the example... here \1 is the first capture group. For your example \1 means "All release related activities". Since I am matching the entire string thus I am replacing it with \1 to provide the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/":"(?:\\[nt])*(.*)}"$/
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ty3z0Q/1/)

1. `":"` Matches ":".
2. `(?:\\[nt])*` Matches 0 or more occurrences of either `\n` or `\t`.
3. `(.*)` Matches 0 or more characters in Capture Group 1 until:
4. `}"$` Matches `}"` followed by the end of the string.

The string you are looking for is in Capture Group 1.